# Paypal Multiple Stage Recurring Payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I would like to know, if Paypal supports multiple stage recurring payment ? 
For instance, can we have payment structure something like this :

1. $10/month for 3 months
2. $20/month for 6 months
3. $30/month thereafter.

The payment is billed every month. I could not find any help in the Paypal developer community, so I am starting to think, such a payment structure is not supported at all.

P.S : It is not a follow-up question to my previous one.

Answer (score 0):

The actual Recurring Payments API only allows for a one time payment that happens when the profile is created, and then you can do a trial amount and period, and then the actual amount and period.  In your case you could just do a $30 one time for the first 3 months, then $20/mo trial period, and then $30/mo until canceled.

Alternatively, you could setup your own recurring payments system using the Preapproval API and then you wouldn't have any limitations (outside of the profiles themselves) on how or when you charge different amounts.